# Mode du verbe après « Comment se fait-il que » ?

Tags: conjugaison, subjonctif, mode-grammatical, indicatif

Quel mode doit-on mettre après « Comment se fait-il que… » ?

Mon intuition me dit de mettre du subjonctif, mais je ne suis pas sûr que cela soit exact.
Par exemple dans la phrase...

> Comment se fait-il qu'il mange si peu ?

Le fait qu'il mange peu est avéré, je le constate. Donc je mettrais plutôt de l'indicatif. Est-ce que mange est à l'indicatif ou au subjonctif ? Dans cette phrase cela ne change rien, mais si je veux utiliser le verbe boire, la différence s'entendra.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ici on exprime un « constat ». Mais il est subjectif. Ceci est la raison pour laquelle le subjonctif doit être utilisé.

Voici [un](http://www.synapse-fr.com/manuels/QUE_INDSUB.htm), [deux](http://www.polarfle.ovh.org/test/avsubjinindica.htm), et [trois](http://homepage3.nifty.com/arrobase/francais/cahier/subjonctif.htm) sites permettant de mieux comprendre où et comment utiliser le subjonctif.

Dans la majorité des cas, les questions qui introduisent une subjectivité de la part de l'orateur sont soumises au subjonctif. Cela concerne aussi tout ce qui touche aux notions traduisant une « volonté » (*je voudrais que tu fasses*) ou un « doute » (*je doute qu'il soit*).

J'irais plus loin, je pense qu'une phrase à l'indicatif aurait pu être « correcte », si, dans un livre, le personnage était omniscient. Dans la littérature, je pense qu'on peut trouver une phrase à l'indicatif pour un tel contexte (mais ce n'est qu'une supposition de ma part). Là cependant, je pense que c'est incorrect.

Answer (score 4):

Les deux sont possibles, le subjonctif me semble le plus courant. (Pour reprendre les mots de Grevisse, le subjonctif se met souvent dans les propositions relatives dans les phrases interrogatives.)

L'Académie française a une [note sur la question](http://www.academie-francaise.fr/la-langue-francaise/questions-de-langue#83_strong-em-subordonne-relative-indicatif-ou-subjonctif-em-strong).  On remarquera qu'elle est tout aussi peu normative (*le plus souvent*, *plus habituel*).  Elle donne un exemple de phrase (non interrogative) où l'utilisation du subjonctif ou pas donne une différence de sens :

> C’est le plus jeune conseiller qui a été élu maire (on constate que c’est le plus jeune, parmi les conseillers actuels, qui vient d'être élu)
>
> C’est le plus jeune conseiller qui ait été élu maire (le locuteur souligne qu’on n’a jamais élu un conseiller plus jeune comme maire)

Answer (score 1):

Pour reprendre l'interrogation de Stéphane, le choix ne semble pas se faire sur la grammaire, mais sur l'attente du questionneur ou l'intention (la présence) du questionné :

*.. que personne ne répond :* ici, maintenant, tout de suite, il y a une absence de réponse, pas de personne physiquement présente pour le faire.
*.. que personne ne réponde :* ne soit capable de répondre, il y a une incapacité à fournir la réponse, même si plusieurs personnes sont là.

Le conditionnel induirait une suggestion au *comment* une explication plausible, alors que le présent se contenterait de constater un fait, ou plutôt son absence.

Comment: Sincèrement, c'est une nuance que je ne perçois pas.