# Après lesquels de ces verbes doit-on utiliser le subjonctif ?

Tags: grammaire, verbes, subjonctif, mode-grammatical

Dans les exempes ci-dessous, j'aimerais bien savoir si on doit utiliser le subjonctif et pourquoi ?

> il parait que + ?
>
> il semble que + ?
>
> il me semble que + ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ceci est une réponse à la question originale, de portée plus générale:

> J'aimerais bien savoir après quelles phrases on doit utiliser subjonctif?

---

Le subjonctif présente seulement quatre formes « temporelles », deux d'entre elles — l'imparfait et le plus-que-parfait — sont aujourd'hui d'un usage très rare. Par contre, le présent et le passé s'opposent souvent par une différence aspectuelle en non proprement temporelle:

> Je veux qu'il *achève* son travail aujourd'hui.
>   Je veux qu'il *ait achevé* son travail aujourd'hui.

En opposition avec l'indicatif, le subjonctif a donc peu d'aptitude à situer les actions dans le temps. Ainsi, c'est le présent du subjonctif qu'on utilise pour une action future. De cette inaptitude du mode à situer les actions dans le temps, on tire fréquemment l'idée que le subjonctif convient aux actions « irréelles » ou « virtuelles ». Vérifiée dans de nombreux cas, cette hypothèse est cependant infirmée pas plusieurs types d'emplois. La présence de Paul n'a rien d'« irréel » dans:

> Je suis irrité que Paul *soit* là.

Ni dans:

> Bien que Benjamin *soit* présent, je reste.

---

Le subjonctif se prête à

- l'expression d'un ordre:

  > Que le chien *reste* dehors!
  >   Qu'il *soit* prêt pour le gouter!

  [Le subjonctif pallie ici avec l'impératif.]
- l'expression d'un souhait:

  > Que les hommes *mettent* fin à la guerre!
  >   Vive la Croix-Rouge, *puisses*-tu revenir, plaise au ciel! (sujet placé après le verbe au subjonctif)
- l'expression de possibilité refusée:

  > Moi, que j'*écrive* un livre de grammaire!
- l'expression d'une réfutation polémique d'une opinion:

  > *Je ne sache pas* que la grammaire soit ennuyeuse.

Le subjonctif est obligatoire après *attendre*, *décider*, *décréter*, *dire* (quand il a une valeur injonctive), *défendre*, *douter*, *être nécessaire*, *être possible*, *exiger*, *falloir*, *interdire*, *ordonner*, *préférer*, *souhaiter*…

Le subjonctif peut être utilisé en alternance avec l'indicatif après les verbes d'assertion ou d'opinion utilisés de façon négative (***paraître* et *sembler* tombent dans cette catégorie**):

> Je pense que tu *peux* travailler. (indicatif)
>   Je ne pense pas que tu *puisses* (ou *peux*) travailler.

La forme interrogative peut parfois rendre possible l'emploi du subjonctif en alternance avec l'indicatif:

> Penses-tu que je *puisse* (ou peux) travailler?

Ou dans une subordonnée placée avant la principale…

> Qu'il *ait* (ou qu'il *a*) été refusé au brevet, c'est certain.

Ou dans certains types de propositions relatives…

> Je cherche dans ce village une maison qui *ait* une tourelle.
>   Je cherche dans ce village une maison qui *a* une tourelle.

La relative au subjonctif indique le critère de sélection de la maison cherchée, sans indiquer si elle existe réellement dans le village. À l'indicatif, la relative présuppose l'existence d'une maison à tourelle dans le village.

Le subjonctif est aussi employé:

- après *avant que* et *jusqu'à ce que* (temporelles). Dans ces phrases, le subjonctif passé marquent la postériorité de l'action:

  > Tu es parti avant qu'il *soit* arrivé.
  >   Tu étais parti avant qu'il *fût arrivé*. (son arrivée a été postérieure à ton départ)
- dans les causales, après *non que* qui sert à marquer une cause rejetée:

  > Il a de l'argent, non qu'il *ait travaillé*, mais il a hérité.
- dans les concessives (introduites par *quoique*, *bien que*, …):

  > Quoiqu'il *soit* tard, il fait encore jour.
  >   Si paresseux qu'il *soit*, il a été reçu à son examen.
- dans les finales (obligatoire):

  > On écrit des livres pour qu'ils *soient lus*.
- dans les consécutives (peut être en alternance avec l'indicatif qu'après *de façon que* et *de manière que*):

  > Jacques agit de manière que Paul *réussisse* (ou *réussit*).

---

*Source: Bescherelle*

Comment: Merci pour la révision @StéphaneGimenez, c'est dûr de frapper en français avec un clavier américain...

Comment: Il y a plein de questions à propos de l'emploi du subjonctif dans une tournure de phrase particulière. Avec cette réponse tu tentes de donner un état des lieux général. On pourrait songer à créer une question pour ce genre de réponses.

Comment: Merci de votre suivi

Comment: @Shahgholi.Ardalan Je vous en prie :)

Answer (score -1):

Le subjonctif est utilisé quand on est face à quelque chose de subjectif en général.

Bon dans le cas de ta question c'est un peu plus feintu.

Si le "que" introduit une subordonnée COD ou COI. Son verbe se met :

- **A l' indicatif :** si le verbe de la principale exprime une opinion, une déclaration, une perception et quand le fait est considéré dans sa réalité (J'affirme qu'une hirondelle ne fait pas le printemps. Je crois que tu ne dors pas. Il dit qu'il craint de te voir).
- **Au subjonctif :** après un verbe principal exprimant la volonté, le doute (Il veut que tu croies en lui. Il demandait que tu cédasses), après un verbe principal exprimant un fait simplement envisagé ou souhaité (Je ne crois pas que l'amour soit suffisant. Si vous pensez que l'amour fasse le bonheur vous vous trompez), lorsque la subordonnée est placée en tête de phrase (Que l'amour fasse le bonheur, je ne le pense pas).
- **Au conditionnel :** quand le fait dépend d'une condition - exprimée ou non (Je crois qu'il ferait bien d'y aller. Je suis sûr que les hommes seraient plus heureux s'ils aimaient davantage la vie).

Donc, en fonction de la subordonnée, ça peut changer. Mais souvent on trouve ceci :

> "Il semble que" + subjonctif (doute)
>
> "Il me semble que" + indicatif (opinion)
>
> "Il parait que" + indicatif (opinion générale)

Exceptionnellement (il en fallait bien une...), si "il semble que" a le sens de "il est certain que", on met l'indicatif : "il semble qu'il est en vie" (Molière, Dom Juan, III, 6).

**Voir :**

[Dans quelle situation utilise-t-on le subjonctif ?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/6433/dans-quelle-situation-utilise-t-on-le-subjonctif/6448#6448)

[Mode du verbe après « Comment se fait-il que » ?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/6320/mode-du-verbe-apres-comment-se-fait-il-que/6321#6321)

**Sources :** Dictionnaire des difficultés de la langue française.