# Les conjonctions qui déclenchent le subjonctif

Tags: subjonctif

Plusieurs conjonctions, dont les suivantes, déclenchent et réclament le subjonctif:

1. de peur/de crainte que
2. à condition que
3. à moins que
4. pourvu que
5. avant que
6. sans que
7. trop/assez/pas assez ... pour que
8. jusqu'à ce que

Je saisis que #1 exprime l'émotion et les sentiments, qui provoquent le subjonctif.

Je m'accommode de l'usage pour #2-#4, car ces conjonctions présentent et précèdent des  conditions et les hypothèses qui manquent de certitude.

Néanmoins, pourquoi est-ce que chacune des #5-#8 provoquent le subjonctif ? Où y sont la doute, l'incertitude et la subjectivité nécessaire ?

J'ai consulté [Après lesquels de ces verbes doit-on utiliser le subjonctif ?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/6549/apres-lesquels-de-ces-verbes-doit-on-utiliser-le-subjonctif/6552#6552) et [« Avant que » et « après que » : indicatif ou subjonctif?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/11/avant-que-et-apres-que-indicatif-ou-subjonctif/90#90).

Comment: Aucune de ces conjonctions n'est suivie d'une affirmation, ce qui privilégie l'usage du subjonctif.

Answer (score 2):

En effet, le subjonctif est employé avec des verbes exprimant :

- la volonté, le désir, le souhait
- la nécessité, l'obligation
- l'émotion, le sentiment, l'appréciation
- la possibilité, l'impossibilité, la probabilité, le doute et l'incertitude

Mais il s'emploie également dans des phrases subordonnées après certaines conjonctions ou locutions qui expriment :

- la manière : **sans que**
- le temps : **avant que**, **jusqu'à ce que**, **en attendant que**
- la condition : **à condition que**, **pourvu que**, **à moins que**
- le but : **afin que**, **pour que**
- l'opposition, la concession : **bien que**, **quoi que**, **pourvu que**
- la cause : **de peur que**, **de crainte que**
- l'hypothèse : **en admettant que**, **en supposant que**, **à supposer que**

Comment: Merci bien. D'après vos exemples en gras, est-il correct de généraliser que le subjonctif s'emploie aussi avec des verbes exprimant la maniêre, le temps, la condition, le but, l'opposition, la concession, la cause, et la hypothèse ?

Comment: non...d'après les exemples, on peut juste dire qu'il s'emploie après certaines locutions qui expriment la manière, le temps....

Comment: Merci. Voici ma confusion. Pourquoi est-ce que le subjonctif s'emploie avec des locutions qui expriment la manière, le temps, ..., et l'hypothèse, mais non pas avec les verbes qui les expriment ?