# Difficultés avec le subjonctif

Tags: grammaire, subjonctif

J'ai des difficultés de compréhension du subjonctif. Il n'y a pas de tel mode dans ma langue natale. Mon manuel dit qu'on utilise ce mode quand on parle de sentiments personnels (subjectifs ). Assez logique, mais c'est encore difficile pour moi. Par exemple, pourquoi utilise-t-on le subjonctif dans cette proposition :

> Il est mécontent que vous nous quittiez si vite.

Une personne part - c'est un fait. Ce n'est pas sentiment personnel, n'est-ce pas ? Eh bien, quand je crois sur ce sujet, je commence de croire que presque toutes déclarations sont subjectives...

> Je crois que la terre est plate.

A mon avis ce doit être une déclaration subjective, mais pour autant que je sais c'est une déclaration indicative.

Pourriez-vous m'expliquer clairement quand il faut utiliser subjonctif ? Je souhaite le comprendre.

Comment: J'aimerais noter que, même pour un français natif, il est (phrase indicative :D) quelquefois difficile de choisir entre le subjonctif et l'indicatif. Cependant, je veux te donner un truc simple et facile à utiliser : Si tu peux dire la phrase incise (suivant le que) seule, alors c'est indicatif, sinon c'est subjonctif. Exemple : *La terre est plate.* (Ne change pas le sens de la phrase -> indicatif) *Vous quittez si vite.* (Change le sens de la phrase, le but principale étant de dire que l'autre est mécontent à cause qu'il parte! -> subjonctif)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

La terre est plate, c'est un fait. Elle est plate au moment où tu en parles et on ne peut rien y faire, tu ne souhaites rien d'elle (qu'elle change par exemple) cela n'influe pas sur tes émotions non plus.

Tandis que dans ton second exemple, *"Il est mécontent que vous nous quittiez si vite"*, un sentiment est transmis, *"Il est mécontent"* !
Il se passe quelque chose dans le temps *"Il nous quitte"* (il ne l'a pas fait, mais il est en train ou va le faire).

Un autre exemple concret : *"Je souhaite qu'il s'en aille"* ; Tu souhaites quelque chose dans le temps *"Qu'il parte"*.

On utilise donc le subjonctif pour certains cas:

- Le doute
- L'incertitude
- L'éventuel

Et qui n'a pas été encore réalisé !

La différence entre dire *"Il est en train de..."* et *"Je souhaite que..."* (subjonctif dans le deuxième cas) est qu'un souhait, une opinion... est transmis !

Jette un coup d'oeil :
http://la-conjugaison.nouvelobs.com/regles/conjugaison/mode-subjonctif-41.php

Answer (score 5):

Dire que le subjonctif est utilisé dans certains cas pour parler de sentiments personnels est vrai mais insuffisant. Je dirais plutôt que le subjonctif est le mode de l'interprétation : c'est le mode qu'on utilise pour apprécier la réalisation ou **les possibilités que l'action se réalise**.

> Il est mécontent que vous nous quittiez si vite.

C'est l'**expression d'un sentiment**.

> Je ne crois pas que la terre soit plate.

C'est l'**expression d'une opinion**.

Le [tableau de Bonjour de France](http://www.bonjourdefrance.com/exercices/contenu/17/grammaire/62.html) reprend de façon synthétique les différents emplois du subjonctif. Et l'exercice qui suit permet de vérifier si on a compris les cas d'emplois.

Ensuite il faut savoir (il faut que tu saches) que le subjonctif est obligatoire :

- après certains verbes.

J'attends que ...
C'est bien que ...
Je ne crois pas que ...
Je ne suis pas sûr que ...
C'est dommage que...
Je demande que ...
Je doute que ...
Il faut que ...
Il faudrait que ...
Je suis ravi/content que ...
Il est possible/impossible que...
Je préfère que ...
Je souhaite que ...
Je veux que ...

Cette liste n'est pas exhaustive.

- Et après certaines conjonctions. Liste dans une [réponse précédente sur French Language](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/6748/358).

Remarque la différence entre la forme affirmative et la forme négative :

> Je crois que la terre est plate. (indicatif)
>   Je ne crois pas que la terre soit plate. (subjonctif)

Comment: Oui, il y a une grande liste des cas dans lesquels on doit utiliser le subjonctif dans mon manuel. Je veux sentir subjonctif français, pas savoir tous les cas :-)