# Use of subjonctif

Tags: subjonctif

I was wondering if the 'subjonctif' is used often nowadays? When I learnt it at school, my teacher said that you can't speak French without it. Is this actually true?

Comment: Trust your teacher! Subjonctif is inescapable in French.

Comment: Extensive answers on when the subjunctive is required: [Difficultés avec le subjonctif](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/11666/358), [Les conjonctions qui déclenchent le subjonctif](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/6722/358).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Subjonctif is absolutely required to correctly express basic things such as doubt, duty, hypotheticals, etc.

Some *tenses* of subjonctif (specifically the past tenses) are currently no longer used as much as they used to outside of the literary context.