# Why the use of subjunctive?

Tags: subjonctif

I’d like to know why the subjunctive is used here for I had the idea?

> J'ai continué à enseigner à l'Institut français jusqu'à ce que **j'aie** l'idée de créer le podcast innerFrench.  À ce moment-là, une nouvelle aventure a commencé.

Comment: Related: https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/6722/les-conjonctions-qui-d%c3%a9clenchent-le-subjonctif

Answer (score 1):

The subjunctive follows « jusqu'à ce que », which is just something to memorise, as well as you have to memorise that it follows « pour que », and other such locutions. See this reference for a useful list: [Banque de dépannage linguistique](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?t1=1&id=4238).

Comment: Addition of references, when it is possible to do so, is a plus.